# Can I mix DDR3 1333 MHz memory with 1666MHz memory on my iMac?

Tags: mac, memory

I have 2x4GB 1333MHz RAM (Mac memory).  Could I add it to my 2012 iMac  with 2x4GB 1666MHz RAM so I have 4x4GB RAM?.  Will it just run at the slower speed or will this just not work?

Answer (score 4):

You can mix memory speeds so long as the memory is *faster* than the memory specified for your computer.

The [2012 iMac calls for PC3-12800 DDR3](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-2.7-21-inch-aluminum-late-2012-specs.html) and the minimum RAM speed is 1600Mhz (all models iMac in 2012; 21" and 27").  So, the 1666MHz RAM will work, but the slower 1333MHz RAM will not. Many, many years of experience has told me not to mix RAM speeds.  While it is "supposed" to work just fine, some memory modules aren't very tolerant and can cause issues.  Stick with what's recommenced for best reliability.

Comment: second this. while in theory it should work fine to mix 1666MHz with 1333MHz chips as long as even the 1666MHz chips are capable of running at 1333MHz (or as long as all the chips have a common lower speed they all support), my personal experience has been that it causes hard to detect memory corruptions and instability in practice =/

Comment: Sounds a bit too conservative and potentially troublesome? 'Recommended' a speed may be, but quiite a few Macs not only tolerate, but *use* faster modules at the faster spec. What's asking for trouble seems to be mixing modules (buy in pairs is better): so even a 'recommended' 1333 mix of modules seems much less reliable to me than a combo of identical modules (manufacturer etc) at 1600 or higher? (The 1333/1600 in my book is automatically disqualified as one such 'mix' that 'might work' but should be avoided if possible)